# Error in trying to create new Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I am trying to create a new Android project in Eclipse ..

But I get the following Error ..!!!!!

- A Package name cannot start or end with a dot
- it also shows error simple in " Theme "

This is the Names I have specify :

- Application Name : test
- Project Name : test
- Package Name : test.pack
- Min SDK : API8 (Android 2.2 )
- Target : API17 (Android 4.2)

!!!!!!
could somebody tell me what is wrong ?!!!

I have update all the packages in the SDK manager ..

and I also went to Help >>Check for update

but it says that :

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Software being installed: Android DDMS 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720)

Missing requirement: Android DDMS 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that yout not installed the SDK Platform on your computer. 
You must open "Window->Android SDK Manager" and then clicked on "SDK Platform"

Comment: I have update all the packages in the SDK Manager but the problem  still appearing !!!!

Comment: i also tried to go to Help>>Check for Updates .. But it shows that >>>>>>>>>>>Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720)
  Missing requirement: Android DDMS 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0' but it could not be found